# find map c++ is not finding key already added in the map

Tags: c++, dictionary, fault

The map cidades starts empty.

Consider the txt file as:

" city1, city2  "

It should add the city with a random number, which is count, when the city is not in the map

Here is the code:

```
 int i,cont = 0;   // i is used as a flag and count do add a key reference when I add a new element in the map
 string line;      // used to get everything  untill the comma

 map<string,int> cidades;    // map of cities and their references .. like cidades<"Silicon Valley", 1>

 ifstream arquivoTexto ("text.txt");  

 if (arquivoTexto.is_open()) {   // open file
    while (getline (arquivoTexto,line)){  // while EOF is false

        stringstream element(line);  i = 1;  // i is always 1 when checking a new line

 while(getline(element, line, ',')){     // line is the string untill the comma
            if(i == 1) {    // i = 1 means the current line is the city one

                std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = cidades.find(line);   // try to find the current city in the map

                if(cidades.empty()){  // insert first time because map is empty 
                    cidades.insert(pair<string,int>(line,cont));
                }
                else if(it == cidades.end()){    // insert because is not in the map
                    cidades.insert(pair<string,int>(line,cont));
                    c1 = cont;
                }else{                      // get the key because is already in the map
                    c1 = cidades.at(line);
                }
            } else if( i == 2) {
                // line is holding city 2, do the same above
            }
    cont++; i++;      // increase i to tell we are working with the next string after the comma
 }
```

But when I put the same code out of the conditionals above.. it works

```
string a = "teste";   // taken from the txt and added into the map
std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = cidades.find(a);
cout << "ele: " << it->first  << " chave: " << it->second;
```

it prints teste and the key... but when I try to print inside the if I got segmentation fault(core dumped).

Edit:
My program can't find a key that's already in the map.
when I compare the iterator in the if statement it looks like none key is in the map( even when the key is already on it,then it add the same key again with another integer reference). So now I'm trying to figure out another way to look for keys in the map,any good ideas?

Comment: `gdb -ex run --args ./name_of_your_program arguments_if _needed`, `bt`, `info locals`, ...

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You try to print `it->first` and `it->second` whether or not anything was found. That can't be right.

Comment: That's right David, my fault, but when I change the if to    "if( it->first != line)" still not works...

Comment: What I'am trying to do is look for something and make tests..if found or not something

Comment: @EduardoHumberto How would changing the `if` so that it still tries to access `it->first` fix the problem that you're accessing `it->first` without first making sure the iterator refers to anything?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz code upgraded David. The iterator refers map::end when the key was not found, otherwise refers to an iterator to it .

Comment: If you now have a different question from the original one, please start a different thread.

Comment: `if(cidades.empty){` That `if` will always fire. Did you mean `if(cidades.empty())`?

Comment: What is `c1`? Why are you only doing anything with the map when `i == 1`, i.e. on the 1st pass? Why `c1 = cidades.at(line);` instead of simply `c1 = *it;`? _What does any of this mean?_ Again, post a MCVE or _at least_ a complete and thoroughly commented version of your actual code plus sample input data. Trying to understand a context-free snippet from someone else's project is pointless.

Comment: Yeah David, wrote it wrong, but it's right in my code... @underscore_d c1 is used to get the reference if key is already in the map... when you I "map.at(something)" it returns a reference of it in the map... for example map<'a',1>    --  map.at('a') returns 1  --- I will upgrade a complete version

Comment: I know what `at()` does... My point is that it has to effectively do another `find()` when there's no need because by that time, you know you have a valid [ non-`end()` ] iterator that can be dereferenced to get the element, without having to wastefully check whether it exists again. Anyway, that's not the main problem with this question.

Comment: "when I put the same code out of the conditionals above.. it works" - _show us_ the _exact_ code you used in this case, showing _exactly where_ you put the `cout`. Anything else is, again, pointless speculation.

Comment: @underscore_d the cout is not the problem anymore, read the Edit in the final of the question, my problem now is that I my code is not finding a city when it was already added. so it == cidades.end() is always trye

Comment: "anymore" - was it ever? If you fixed the old problem, explain how in an answer. If you have a new problem, open a new thread - not a small, easy-to-miss edit to the original, now irrelevant text. And in either case: "Again, post a MCVE or at least a complete and thoroughly commented version of your actual code plus sample input data" - and, of course, the expected result. Otherwise, there is no point to anyone speculating about why your file isn't being read as you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll open a news thread, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because `line` isnt found, in which case `it` would be set to map::end, and I think that basically means its set to 'NULL' or some invalid location which means you shouldn't dereference it i.e: `it->first` (hence the segmentation fault) (technically what happens if you dereference the iterator returned from `find` when it doesn't find anything, is undefined behaviour, i.e. don't do it.),

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Don't do the `cout` there, do it in the 'else' below, where you know `it` is pointing to a valid item.

Comment: No, the end() value does not "basically means its set to NULL". At least not in `std::map`'s case.

Comment: what does it mean? what happens if you dereference 'end'?

Comment: What happens is "undefined behavior".

Comment: The case it is set to map::end is when I try to find something, but I didn't find it, so it == end, isn't it right?

Comment: yes the if statement is correct, however the fact that the `cout` is outside it means it could be trying to print `it` when `it == end` and you shouldn't got `it->` when `it == end`

Comment: That's right, but this if statement is always true, don't know why, never jump to the else, even when the key is already added in the map

Comment: could that be the outer `if(i==1)`  this `if` will only ever be entered once.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `if(i==1)`?

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to do is get a line, and if that line isn't already in the dictionary, add it to the dictionary with the line number as the value, if it is already in the dictionary, get the current value, which will be the line number of the first instance of that line

Comment: That's right matt, but this is the format of the line "city1, city2, distance " , and the if statement is used to know if(i==1) I getting city1, if(i==2) getting city 2 and else I'm getting the distance between them

Comment: Guys you won't believe me, but the reason of all problems was an extra space in the txt file. I'm using getline, so when getting the same string with the extra space, it won't be found in the map, thank you all for your help!